# NSString with umlaute from char array

Tags: ios5, encoding, character-encoding, nsstring

i have this array:

```
const char array[3] = {173,67,0};
```

and i would like to get an NSString which looks like " °C " (ISO Latin1).
I've tried some encodings, but don't get it...

---

Thanks. I tried your code:

```
const char array[3] = {176, 67, 0};
NSString *degreeC = [NSString stringWithCString: array encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"%@");
```

Unfortunately, this results in an output of

```
¬∞C
```

And the same, if i use

```
NSString *degree2 = @"°C"; 
NSLog(degree2);
```

Have i to make any settings in xcode?

Answer (score 0):

You said you wanted an umlaut but in your example you drew a degree sign. In ISO Latin-1 an umlaut is 0xa8 (decimal 168) and a degree sign is 0xb0 (decimal 176). If really are starting from a C string and you need an NSString from it:

```
const char array[3] = { 176, 67, 0 };
NSString *degreeC = [NSString stringWithCString:array encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
```

alternately, since you can directly use non-ASCII characters in your source code in Xcode (default encoding is UTF-8) you could just make an NSString literal:

```
NSString *degreeC = @"°C";
```